# Как центрировать текст в phpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Нужно в объедененном поле сделать текст по центру не только относительно левого/правого края, но и относительно верха/низа. 
Пример как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpExcel уже давно [не поддерживается](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel#phpexcel---deprecated).

> All users should migrate to its direct successor PhpSpreadsheet, or
>   another alternative

Используйте [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). Документация [тут](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells)

```
$spreadsheet
->getActiveSheet()
->getStyle('A1:D4')
->getAlignment()
->setVertical(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
```

Если всё же нужен phpExcel, то так ([документация](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/develop/Documentation))

```
$style = array(
    'alignment' => array(
        'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
    )
);

$sheet->getStyle("A1:B1")->applyFromArray($style);
```

или так

```
$sheet->getStyle($column.$style)->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
```

Comment: нужно именно с phpExcel это сделать...

Comment: @Денис дополнил ответ

Comment: @Денис ну что??

Comment: не работает. он просто выравнивает по центру относительно левого/правого края. а ячейка высокая, получается текст по центру, но внизу ячейки. как у меня на примере (второе фото)

Comment: @Денис А, сорян. смотри ответ.